# The Pin is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mapkit

My Map shows a pin on a specific place but it's not showing the pin

Here is the code

WadiRumViewControllerJordan.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface WadiRumViewControllerJordan : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *WadiRumMapView;
@end
```

WadiRumViewControllerJordan.m

```
#import "WadiRumViewControllerJordan.h"
#import "WadiRumNSOjectPIN.h"

@interface WadiRumViewControllerJordan ()


@end
//Wadi Rum Coordinates
#define WadiRum_Latitude 29.537355
#define WidiRum_longtitude 35.415026

//Wadi Rum Span
#define WadiRumSpan 0.01f;


@implementation WadiRumViewControllerJordan
@synthesize WadiRumMapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Create WadiRum Region
    MKCoordinateRegion WadiRumRegion;

    //Center
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = WadiRum_Latitude;
    center.longitude = WidiRum_longtitude;

    //Span
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = WadiRum_Latitude;
    span.longitudeDelta = WidiRum_longtitude;

    WadiRumRegion.center = center;
    WadiRumRegion.span = span;

    //Set our map
    [WadiRumMapView setRegion:WadiRumRegion animated:YES];

    //WadiRumNSObjectPIN
    //1. Create a coordinate for the use of WadiRum
    CLLocationCoordinate2D WadiRumLocation;
    WadiRumLocation.latitude = WadiRum_Latitude;
    WadiRumLocation.longitude = WidiRum_longtitude;

    WadiRumNSOjectPIN * WadiRumAnnitation = [[WadiRumNSOjectPIN alloc] init];
    WadiRumAnnitation.coordinate = WadiRumLocation;
    WadiRumAnnitation.title = @"Services";
    WadiRumAnnitation.subtitle = @"Desert";



    {[self.WadiRumMapView addAnnotation:WadiRumAnnitation];

    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be WadiRumNSOjectPIN
}



@end
```

WadiRumNSOjectPIN.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface WadiRumNSOjectPIN : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property(nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString * title;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString * subtitle;

@end
```

WadiRumNSOjectPIN.m

```
#import "WadiRumNSOjectPIN.h"

@implementation WadiRumNSOjectPIN
@synthesize coordinate;

- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        coordinate = coord;
    }
    return self;
}

@synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle;

@end
```

I edited the code above to make it exactly like what I want, I got this error in the picture bellow

[image: Picture]

Comment: I'm confused by, "my map shows a pin on a specific place but it's not showing the pin". So does it show a pin or not? Have you implemented the delegate method to add a MKPinAnnotationView?

Comment: @JoshHamet - Even without specifying the delegate, he'd see the default behavior of showing the pin with standard callout behavior.

Comment: Roa, you have a line that says `[ttNSOjectPIN alloc];`. Make sure you always call `init`, too, e.g. `[[ttNSOjectPIN alloc] init];`.

Comment: Ya true good point, more concerned about that first statement

Comment: @Rob I added it, it shows the pic but in a different place!

Comment: Its showing up in wrong place because you never set `coordinate` property. Retire `ttcoordinate` property and replace it with `coordinate`. (Same with `tttitle` and `ttsubtitle`.)

Comment: @Rob I changed them, but still :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to conform to `MKAnnotation`, you must have properties called `coordinate`, `title` and `subtitle`. You've added three extra properties, `ttcoordinate`, `tttitle`, and `ttsubtitle`, but `MKAnnotation` is going to ignore those, and will look for `coordinate`, `title`, and `subtitle`.

The key reason you're not seeing your annotation is that you're setting `ttcoordinate` in `viewDidLoad`. But `MKAnnotation` will not use that, but rather will refer to the `coordinate` property you synthesized, but never set. (You do have an `initWithLocation` method, which suggests you were going to update `coordinate`, but you never call that.)

Bottom line, I would suggest renaming `ttcoordinate`, `ttitle` and `ttsubtitle` to `coordinate`, `title`, and `subtitle`, and updating all of those references accordingly, and that should fix everything. And you can retire the `@synthesize` line.

Comment: I'll try it now, hold on!

Comment: Remove the synthesize line if you declare the properties.